# ImportError: cannot import name 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I have ggplot successfully installed in my python 3.6.3 using the code below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ggplot
```

But when I import it in my notebook using the code below, I get an error:

```
from ggplot import *
ImportError: cannot import name 'Timestamp'
```

I would appreciate any idea on how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem.

Please go to .../site-packages/ggplot/stats/smoothers.py and change

```
from pandas.lib import Timestamp
```

to

```
from pandas import Timestamp
```

and save.

Comment: can you do this from a Jupyter notebook? I'm on a shared server and I don't have access to those directories. By the way, did something _just_ happen to cause this? I imported ggplot on the same server yesterday with no problem, and now I notice this question is only 1 day old...

Comment: hi, my best guest for your situation is that someone upgrades the pandas package in the sever which causes Timestamp is deprecated from pandas.lib and the resulting error. I can only come up with two solutions: 1. use virtualenv package to create your own environment so that you can have access to those directories; 2. downgrade the pandas package to a suitable version(not quite sure)

Answer (score 15):

@Liaoming999 is correct but adding more changes to resolve this problem:

1. Open file `../site-packages/ggplot/stats/smoothers.py`
2. Change `from pandas.lib import Timestamp` to `from pandas import Timestamp` in line 4
3. Change `pd.tslib.Timestamp` to `pd.Timestamp` in line 14.
4. Save the file
5. Open file `../site-packages/ggplot/utils.py` and goto line 81 and do the same as step 3. Thanks to @wmsmith for this tip.

**p.s.**: General advise is to use Anaconda or some Virtual env.

Comment: I just finished a fresh install on a brand new imac. Apparently, this same thing must be done in ../site-packages/ggplot/utils.py as well. So after updating stats/smoothers.py and utils.py ggplot could finally be imported.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading to pandas 0.23 on a databricks server.

Had to come up with this command-line solution using the unix `sed` tool:

```
cd .../python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ggplot/stats/
sed -i 's/pandas.lib/pandas/g' smoothers.py
```

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with @Srikar Appalaraju. Additionally, update the line 81 in utils.py (path is .../site-packages/ggplot/utils.py) from "pd.tslib.Timestamp" to "pd.Timestamp" to remove FutureWarning.

Answer (score 2):

There has been little going on for a while in `ggplot` - maybe it'll change in the future, and the main project comes around.

In the meantime, instead of hacking the library (which is sometimes hard), you can use this friendly fork:

https://github.com/sushinoya/ggpy

Further reading:
https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/654

Install using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sushinoya/ggpy
```

or:

```
pip install --user git+https://github.com/sushinoya/ggpy
```

(the latter may work in a shared server environment)

Caveats:
you'll need Git, and maybe a working compiler for Python extensions.