# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.lib'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

`from ggplot import mtcars`

While importing mtcars dataset from ggplot on jupyter notebook i got this error
My system is *windows 10* and I've already reinstalled and upgraded pandas (also used --user in installation command)but it didn't work out as well. Is there any other way to get rid of this error?

> \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ggplot\stats\smoothers.py in 
> 2                         unicode_literals)
> 3 import numpy as np
> ----> 4 from pandas.lib import Timestamp
> 5 import pandas as pd
> 6 import statsmodels.api as sm
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.lib'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'Timestamp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591982/importerror-cannot-import-name-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

> I Just tried out a way. I hope this works out for others as well. I changed from this

```
from pandas.lib import Timestamp
```

to this

```
from pandas._libs import Timestamp
```

as the path of the module is saved in path C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas-libs
is _libs
Also, I changed from

```
date_types = (
    pd.tslib.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

to this

```
date_types = (
    pd._tslib.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

Before that, I went on this path "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ggplot\util.py" to make the same changes in util.py for date_types. This helped me out to get rid of the error I mentioned in my question.